# Database server for a simple java desktop application

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-7

I want to ask best server for a simple desktop java application.
Please suggest me a server using which i can port my database files on another computer.
can i have an option of MYSQL server 5.1.
in which i develop my application and then i can easily port it to another computer as it is with database.

Comment: You can consider using Oracle because Oracle export command is really powerful

Comment: you mean embedded database or not , is it possible for you to install same database on every system your application has ??

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure about your application requirements, but for simple application look at embedded databases like [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/).

MySQL and really any other database are also quite straightforward to transfer via data dump/load. In case of MySQL even the data files copy will work.

Comment: also take a look at H2 database as it is written in java and supports being embedded into application unlike MySQL